# List Directory Folder Names & Subdirectory Folder Names Only & in Sorted Order

Tags: directory-listing, directory-structure

I am trying to use the DIR command to create a list of Folder names with the names of any and all subfolders listed after the parent folder name - but just the names of the folders.

So if the tree looks like:

```
Folder1

  subfoldera

  subfolderb

Folder2

  subfolderc

  subfloderd
```

The list would be essentially that:

```
Folder1

subfoldera

subfolderb

Folder2

subfolderc

subfloderd
```

Only folder names with no files listed, without any attributes and without the leading directory tree information.  Is that even doable ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking for the windows command prompt

```
 dir /s /ad /b /on
```

Will list only directory names but, will display the full path

Comment: Thanks, Shyam, I've tried that, but that lists the top folders first and then the subfolders, not in the sequence as per the original question and it also lists the directory tree information as a suffix to the folder name, rather than just the folder names as in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Well I never solved this via a command line option, but I did finally come across a flexible and useful free utility that will do what I was looking to do.  It is called Karen's Directory Printer (your favorite search engine will find it) and once you figure out which options to include/exclude it will print out just the folder names with the children folder names under the appropriate parent folder name.  Thought I would share...